# Reverse proxy nginx and Express server returning 502

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, docker, dockerfile

I am running a single VPS with an Nginx reverse proxy configuration forwarding to three Angular websites. Each site is running inside its own Docker container behind an Express server.

The first two sites I got up and running no problem. They are simple Angular sites with the `server.js` and `index.html` files at the base of the project's directory.

For the third site I got a little fancier and am using Grunt to build the project files into a new directory called `public`. My goal is to have the site viewable from this public directory.

Here's my `nginx.conf` file. Note that the first two server blocks are working as expected. Browsing to the third, however, results in "502 Bad Request":

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com domain2.ca;
    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:9001;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub1.domain1.com sub1.domain2.ca;
    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:9002;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
// THIS IS THE SERVER THAT IS NOT WORKING
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub2.domain1.com sub2.domain2.ca;
    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:9003;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

This is the file that starts up my Express server. All three projects have very similar servers, but this one serves static files at `/public` instead of just `/`

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = 80;
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
  console.log("server listening on port " + port);
});
```

Lastly, because this site is inside a docker container, here's my Dockerfile for building it:

```
# Start with angular node grunt bower setup
FROM brymastr/angular:latest

# Add to working dir
WORKDIR /src
ADD . /src

# install dependencies
RUN     npm install
RUN     bower install --allow-root
RUN     sudo apt-get -y install ruby-full
RUN     sudo gem install sass
RUN     grunt build

# Run application
EXPOSE  80
CMD ["nodemon", "server.js"]
```

This image works just fine when running the container on both of my local dev environments. This makes me think that the issue is with the nginx configuration on the VPS.

To recap: nginx takes the request and forwards it to the port assigned for the docker container that runs the site. The container's express server picks up the request and serves the files in the `/public` folder of the project.

Am I missing something when it comes to the routing between nginx and express?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am still new at this and I'm just trying to save some money running small sites on one VPS. There's probably a better/simpler way to do this but this is what I've come up with for now. I've searched extensively and tried much including having express serve static files at `/` and having nginx proxy pass to `127.0.0.1:9003/public` but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: you ever solve this?

Comment: I never solved this specific problem, however I moved away from manually writing my nginx conf files to using docker-gen with [docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion#user-content-separate-containers-recommended-method) and since then I've moved on to using [Traefik](https://github.com/containous/traefik)